# Flutter how to get the passed or populated existing data that not belong to TextEditingWidget through widget

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, widget, crud

I still new learner in flutter, I currently learning to complete on a project CRUD operation of Firebase Firestore. I need to retrieve the the existing data and populate or pass back to the update task page through widget. Currently only the title and note that using TextEditingController() with the widget.title and widget.note that declared able to insert into controller field of InputField able to get back the data and display, other fields will be display back the default values. How can I display back the existing data of date, startTime, repeat, color and remind through widget as they are not TextEditingController type and I could not use the same ways to implement it? I need help guys, appreciate your help, thank you.

**Images:**
[image: Original data that inserted]
[image: Update task page that only able get back title and note existing data, other is default value]

**UpdatingTaskPage Class Code:**

```
class UpdatingTaskPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id, title, note, date, startTime, endTime, repeat;
  final int color, remind;
  final bool isCompleted;

  const UpdatingTaskPage(
      {super.key,
      required this.id,
      required this.title,
      required this.note,
      required this.date,
      required this.startTime,
      required this.endTime,
      required this.repeat,
      required this.color,
      required this.remind,
      required this.isCompleted});

  @override
  State<UpdatingTaskPage> createState() => _UpdatingTaskPageState();
}

class _UpdatingTaskPageState extends State<UpdatingTaskPage> {
  static TaskController controller = Get.put(TaskController());
  final task = controller.tasks.length;

  TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController noteController = TextEditingController();

  late DateTime _selecteDate = DateTime.now();
  late String _startTime =
      DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(DateTime.now()).toString();
  String _endTime = DateFormat('hh:mm a')
      .format(DateTime.now().add(const Duration(minutes: 60)))
      .toString();
  int _selectedRemind = 5;
  List<int> remindList = [5, 10, 15, 20];
  String _selectedRepeat = 'None';
  List<String> repeatList = ['None', 'Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly'];
  int _selectedColor = 0;
  List<Color> colorList = [
    bluishClr,
    yellowClr,
    redClr,
    greenClr,
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    titleController.text = widget.title;
    noteController.text = widget.note;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Update task!"),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // this icon button is for the user to signout
                AuthController.instance.logout();
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.logout_rounded))
        ],
      ),
      body:Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              //Title
              InputField(
                title: 'Title',
                hint: 'Enter your title here...',
                controller: titleController,
              ),
              //Note
              InputField(
                title: 'Note',
                hint: 'Enter your note here...',
                controller: noteController,
              ),
              //Date
              InputField(
                title: 'Date',
                hint: DateFormat.yMd().format(_selecteDate),
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () => _getDateFromUser(),
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.calendar_today_outlined,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              //Date Range
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: InputField(
                      title: 'Start Time',
                      hint: _startTime,
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => _getTimeFromUser(isStartTime: true),
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.access_time_rounded,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: InputField(
                      title: 'End Time',
                      hint: _endTime,
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => _getTimeFromUser(isStartTime: false),
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.access_time_rounded,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              //Remind
              InputField(
                title: 'Alert',
                hint: '$_selectedRemind minutes early',
                child: DropdownButton(
                  onChanged: (String? newVal) {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedRemind = int.parse(newVal!);
                    });
                  },
                  items: remindList
                      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                        (e) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: e.toString(),
                          child: Text('$e minutes'),
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                    size: 32,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  elevation: 3,
                  underline: Container(height: 0),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
              ),
              //Repeat
              InputField(
                title: 'Repeat',
                hint: _selectedRepeat,
                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                  onChanged: (String? value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedRepeat = value!;
                    });
                  },
                  value: widget.repeat,
                  items: repeatList
                      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                        (e) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: e,
                          child: Text(e),
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                    size: 32,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  elevation: 3,
                  underline: Container(height: 0),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
              ),
              //Color
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Text('Color'),
                    Row(
                      children: List.generate(
                        colorList.length,
                        (index) => Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0, top: 8),
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                Value(widget.color);
                                _selectedColor = index;
                              });
                            },
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: colorList[index],
                              child: index == _selectedColor
                                  ? const Icon(
                                      Icons.check,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    )
                                  : null,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        //   ); // edited
        // } // edited
        // ); // edited
        // } // edited
      ),
      floatingActionButton: MyButton(
          label: 'Save',
          onTap: () {
            _validateData();
          }),
    );
  }

  _validateData() async {
    if (titleController.text.isNotEmpty && noteController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      print(1);
      _updateTaskToDb();
      Get.back();
    } else if (titleController.text.isEmpty || noteController.text.isEmpty) {
      print(2);

      Get.snackbar(
        'Required',
        'All fileds are required',
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
        colorText: Colors.black,
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.warning_amber_rounded,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      print('######## Error Here ! ########');
    }
  }

  _updateTaskToDb() async {
    await FirestoreDB.updateTask(
      taskModel: Task(
        id: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
        title: titleController.text,
        note: noteController.text,
        isCompleted: false,
        date: DateFormat.yMd().format(_selecteDate),
        startTime: _startTime,
        endTime: _endTime,
        color: _selectedColor,
        remind: _selectedRemind,
        repeat: _selectedRepeat,
      ),
      documentId: widget.id,
    );
  }

  _getDateFromUser() async {
    DateTime? _pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: _selecteDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(2020),
      lastDate: DateTime(2030),
    );
    if (_pickedDate != null) {
      setState(() {
        Value(widget.date);
        _selecteDate = _pickedDate;
      });
    } else {
      print('picked date empty !');
    }
  }

  _getTimeFromUser({required bool isStartTime}) async {
    TimeOfDay? _pickedTime = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
    );
    if (_pickedTime != null) {
      setState(() {
        if (isStartTime) {
          _startTime = _pickedTime.format(context);
          print(_startTime);
        } else {
          _endTime = _pickedTime.format(context);
          print(_endTime);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```